# route landline phone in elastix

Tags: voip, elastix

Im from Colombia, so my english isn't perfect.

On our campus there are several SMEs which we offer some services. The company I work for has several landlines phone numbers :
6455281 , 6455282 , 6455283 , etc. And an GrandStream ip phone with extension 1201. 
We own a console with Elastix v.2.3 with freePBX , phone lines listed above all pass through the PBX , enter through the same trunk . 
Please someone could tell me how to route one of the numbers listed so that when they call that number does not pass through the PBX but sound directly to the Grandstream phone?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched information on manuals posted on internet and i followed this steps to solve my question:

1. You must have an extension created and running.
2. Go to "Inbount Routes".
3. On "DID number" type the desire telephone number to route.
4. On "Set Destination" choose "extensions" then select an extension from the list.
5. Click on submit.
6. Click on "Apply changes"